# Persistencia de sesión en react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-storage

estoy haciendo un workflow de autenticación en react-native con asyncStorage. Básicamente tengo 2 componentes:
Login --> Si el login es correcto almaceno todos sus datos en asyncStorage y le genero un token
AppRoute --> Con un useEffect llamo la función que me trae el token del storage y en base a eso quiero renderizar el Dashboard si efectivamente existe el token y sino el Login.
Funciona pero tengo que recargar la app para que reflejen los cambios, ya probé pasandole sessionToken como dependencia al useEffect pero sigue el problema.

Login:

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const storeUser = async (user) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const user = {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      token: token()
    }
        await storeUser(user);
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
        
    }
```

AppRoute:

```
const AppRoute = () => {
  //Averiguar porqué no actualiza el token sin recargar la app.
  const [sessionToken, setSessionToken] = useState(null);

  const checkSessionPersistence = async () => {
    try {
      const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
      console.log('USER DATA DEL ASYNC : ', userData)
      const { token } = JSON.parse(userData);
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  
  const getSessionToken = async () => {
    const token = await checkSessionPersistence();
    setSessionToken(token);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getSessionToken();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {sessionToken ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```